# How would I justify that I have found all solutions to a simultaneous congruence question.

Tags: linear-algebra

A reoccurring question in a past paper is 'solve and justify that you have found all solutions to the simultaneous congruence equations (2).' How would I do this? Lets say I've solved it, what would I say\do?

Comment: Is it a set of linear congruences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the uniqueness part of the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Theorem_statement)?